# Connect to ESP8266 running micropython from PUTTY

Tags: putty, esp8266, micropython

I am attempting to connect to an ESP8266 Board running micropython with no luck.  I have erased and flashed per the instructions in the docs and all instructions found on internet.  See below (this is on Windows 10):

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\MicroPython\firmware>esptool.py --port com3 erase_flash
esptool.py v2.5.1
Serial port com3
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 60:01:94:70:fc:da
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 2.5s
Hard resetting via RTS pin...

C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\MicroPython\firmware>esptool.py --port com3 --baud 460800 write_flash --flash_size=detect 0 esp8266-20180511-v1.9.4.bin
esptool.py v2.5.1
Serial port com3
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 60:01:94:70:fc:da
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Flash params set to 0x0040
Compressed 604872 bytes to 394893...
Wrote 604872 bytes (394893 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 9.3 seconds (effective 522.8 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...

C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\MicroPython\firmware>
```

---

The board has AMICA printed on the back. See pic of the front.  It is connected on `COM3` via `USB`.

[image: Amica Board]

---

When I connect to the board with PUTTY I get gibberish and the terminal is non-responsive.

**Putty Serial Settings:**

```
Speed: 115200
Data bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow Control: None
```

When I hit reset on the board the gibberish on putty terminal clears and more appears.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Comment: That looks like a NodeMCU board, and if so then as far as I can see you're following the instructions correctly. Could your USB-serial driver be incorrect? Have you tried any other terminal programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those other newbies out there who stumble across this with similar problems...

I bought a new board, flashed it as above and connected with putty with the settings I have listed above with no issues.  So I am guessing a bad board.  Finally, I can get back to programming in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I also had some Putty issues.  Turning off Flow Control in Putty helped everything tremendously.  I still get a line of garbage on a reset, but after that it all works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your baud rate to 9600, it eighter runs on 115200 or 9600. if it looks like gibberish try change it. As a starter

Comment: at 9600 I get a blank screen, still unresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the board with micropython solved the gibberish problem for me